# autoreconf cleanup

Tags: autotools

I use `autoreconf --install` to generate configure scripts, etc for my project. Is there a "cleanup" option, or some other easy method to clean up the files generated by autoreconf? With the Makefiles generated by `configure`, I can do a `make distclean`, but I would like to further clean my directory by removing the Makefile.in, etc files.

Answer (score 18):

That command is called `make maintainer-clean`. It will remove nearly everything that `autoreconf` generates, with a few exceptions. Two notable exceptions are `configure` and `Makefile.in`.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html describes the differences between `distclean` and `mainainer-clean`. In my project, they behave exactly the same, although in general maintainer-clean removes a superset of distclean. Both leave Makefile.in, configure, config.h.in, aclocal.m4, files generated in m4/, and files generated in build-aux.

Answer (score 0):

There are no automatic rules to delete .in fiules and configure.

In autotools documentatiion it is strongly recommended to delete nothing that is needed to run ./configure && make.

You can define your own clean rules which will delete these files, but then au are forced to run the complete toolchain to create a new built.